# Select everything but a block of text

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I have a comprehensive host file for a distributed network monitoring system that I need split into two files. Some of the hosts go in one file and the rest go in the other. I'm using `sed` to pull the hosts I need out but I don't know how to put everything else in the other file, kind of like the `-v` option for `grep`.

Example of host file:

```
object Host "router" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "router"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}

object Host "switch" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "switch"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}

object Host "router" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "router"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}

object Host "otherthing" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "otherthing"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}

object Host "switch" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "switch"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}

object Host "otherthing" {
  import "template"
  display_name = "otherthing"
  address = "xx.xx.xx.xx "
}
```

The `sed` command I'm using to pull routers out

```
sed '/router.*\n/p;//g;/{$/,/^}/H;//x;D' files/tmp/unsorted-host.tmp >> files/router.conf
```

Also I don't know if it would be more efficient to the sorting instead of building the large host file but here's how I make the large host file:

```
    while read line
        do
                # The SNMP to check the device type outputs on multiple lines, check to ensure we only grab IP's
                getip=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
                if ping -c 1 $getip &> /dev/null
                        then
                        ip=$getip
                        else
                        trash=$getip
                fi
                template="template"
                host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community1 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}' )
                if [ -z "$host_name" ]
                        then
                        host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community2 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}' )
                        if [ -z "$host_name" ]
                                then
                                host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community3 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}' )
                                if [ -z "$host_name" ]
                                        then
                                        host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community4 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}' )
                                        if [ -z "$host_name" ]
                                                then
                                                host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community5 $ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}' )
                                                if [ -z "$host_name" ]
                                                        then
                                                        host_name=$(echo " Not found ")

                                                fi
                                        fi
                                fi
                        fi
                fi
                echo "
object Host $host_name {
  import \"$template\"
  display_name = $host_name
  address = \"$ip \"
}" 
        done < files/tmp/hosts.tmp > files/tmp/unsorted-hosts.tmp
```

The goal would be to have two files, one with routers and one with everything else. Thanks ahead of time for any and all advice!

Comment: I've not looked at your `sed` statement in detail, but if you're able to find everything you need with `sed`, then can't you also just do a `sed` substitution to delete out the router material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -v RS= '/router/' hosts.txt > routers.txt
awk -v RS= '!/router/' hosts.txt > non_routers.txt
```

or with one awk:

```
awk -v RS= '/router/ {print > "routers.txt"}; !/router/ {print > "non_routers.txt"}' hosts.txt
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer: I find that big nested `if` painful. A quick rewrite:

```
while read -r ip rest_of_line; do
    # The SNMP to check the device type outputs on multiple lines, check to ensure we only grab IP's
    ping -c 1 "$ip" &> /dev/null || continue
    template="template"
    host_name=
    for n in 1 2 3 4 5; do
        host_name=$(timeout -s KILL 2 /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community$n "$ip" 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 | awk '{print $NF}')
        [ -n "$host_name" ] && break
    done
    if [ -z "$host_name" ]; then 
        echo "host not found for ip $ip" >&2
        continue
    fi
    echo "
object Host $host_name {
  import \"$template\"
  display_name = $host_name
  address = \"$ip \"
}" 
done < files/tmp/hosts.tmp > files/tmp/unsorted-hosts.tmp
```

Comment: I wish I could do something like that but the communities are actually text strings. I just replaced them with community1 community2 etc. for privacy.

Comment: Then do `for c in community1 community2 community3 ...`

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you!

This site is really amazing and you all are a great help.